# How to protect htdocs files

Tags: php, html, protected, copy-protection

does anyone know how to make my `htdocs` folder files `uneditable` but can be copy because i want to make my web application secure so that people cant edit the contents inside my files.

Does anyone know how to do this? can be copy but uneditable.

Comment: What "people" are you concerned about at the end of your first sentence? Why would they have access to your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the directory/file permissions to 755 (rwx r_x r_x)

Answer (score 0):

`chown` (change ownership) files/directories to another user than the user that runs the web server than `chgrp` (change group)  that files to the webserver's group than set the permission for group the have a read access and strip the group to have all other unnecessary right.